# Modal Not Popping Up When Clicking Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm doing a walkthrough project to learn bootstrap, everything has been going well however now at a part of the project which I followed perfectly to create a signup modal, the button is not causing the modal to popup.

I have double checked that all my bootstrap links are in the right order, triple checked spelling errors, everything seems to be fine, I see no reason as to why the modal wouldn't work.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign Up!</button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="signUpModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS or JS to make a [mcve] - I for example had to add the bootstrap CSS to the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="signUpModal">
```

To this :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="signUpModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signUpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

I just don't understand why it doesn't work without the .fade class, [since the documentation says it's possible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#remove-animation)...

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot, If you don't understand why it works then I'm never going to solve why haha! Thanks again, this problem had me stumped!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot some tags and ids. You should use :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign Up!</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="signUpModal" tabindex="-1" aria labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Source : [Modal - Bootstrap v4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

Comment: Can you please take OP's snippet and fix that and show what you actually fixed?